# Style every 3 elements in a grid layout with :nth-child

Tags: css, grid, css-selectors

I can't seem to figure this out, below is a image of the grid layout I'm trying to achieve.

So far, all I have is how to target the first 2 rows with the following:

```
.list {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

.list:nth-child(-n+2), .list:nth-child(5n+1) {
    width: 50%;
}

<div class="list"></div>
```

This starts off OK, but begins to fall apart by the 3rd row. Any idea on how this can be achieved?

http://www.mythemer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/grid-style.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.list {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.list:nth-child(5n+3), .list:nth-child(5n+4), .list:nth-child(5n) {
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, now that I see it, it's pretty obvious. I was over thinking it and had to step away and let someone with fresher eyes handle it...Thanks.